# Custom two factor authentication get verification app

Tags: authentication, loginflow, two-factor-authentication

We want to manage external community users with a custom multi factor authentication that takes advantage of the already existing authentication apps (Salesforce Authenticator, Google Authenticator, Microsoft Authenticator...).

To do this, we built a custom login flow that triggers some Visualforce pages (these contain aura components to have a more customized view) where the user is guided to insert all the necessary information.

The issue comes when, before the QR code/key is read from the app (recovered from `Auth.SessionManagement` class), we need to have the app registered beforehand (we believe this should be done with the `TwoFactorMethodsInfo` class). What is the best approach to take?

Comment: Disassemble the [Login Flow package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm) that does this and you'll have your answer.

Comment: With that package we can not have the TOTP authentication method registered from a Visualforce page as the UserManagement.initVerificationMethod does not accept Auth.VerificationMethod.TOTP. And using the UserManagement.registerVerificationMethod redirects to a standard page.

Comment: The example flow shows how this entire sequence works with QR codes and TOTP, thus our suggestion of disassembling.